# Enabling spi1.x bus in android things raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, spi, android-things

As per, rpi3 device tree, it has two spi buses i.e spi0 and spi1.
 spi0 bus supports 2 chip select [spi0.0, spi0.1] and spi1 bus supports 3 chip select[spi1.0, spi1.1, spi1.2] pins. All these can be configured in config.txt using dtoverlay.

Now my rpi3 uses spi0.1 for touchscreen interface. I dont want to use spi0.0 because it may cause bus contention. So i need to connect my other peripheral on spi1.x bus.

When i am querying rpi3 for spi buses using getSpiBusList(), the ouput is [SPI0.0, SPI0.1]

How do i get around this issue?

Note:- Using android things 0.7-devpreview

Answer (score 0):

According [Raspberry Pi I/O pinout](https://pinout.xyz/#) there is only `SPI0.0` and `SPI0.1` `SPI` buses pins, so you can't use `SPI1.?` bus even if you configure it in `config.txt`.